# Add required plugins (dependencies) programmatically to an existing (plugin) project

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

In eclipse I can add required plug-ins (Dependencies) within UI (see screenshot above). This leads to an entry in the manifest.mf file.

My question is: **How can I do this programmatically?**

I imagine something like `myProject.getManifest().addRequiredPlugin(new PluginImport(...`

I already used the Plug-In Selection Spy and copied the used code. The problem is, that internal classes are beeing used there and I don't want to use internal classes. There must be a better way.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible.

Eclipse uses the manifest to load your plug-in, and probably doesn't read it again after that's done, so editing it would have no effect (since your code doesn't run until after your plug-in is loaded). As such, I doubt an interface has been provided to do this.

What are you trying to accomplish? I don't know of any use cases where trying to do this would be a good idea.